# Prediction/Probability Estimation using Regression or Max Likelihood

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood, regression-analysis, linear-regression

Let's say I have a data set of avg. temperatures in a region over 7 years, and the trend is generally increasing.

Example:

2010 = 20.2 degrees,

2011 = 21.9,

2012 = 20.8,

2013 = 22.4,

...

2016 = 25.4

I am interested in finding out whether the avg. temperature will reach a certain level, say 27 degrees or higher by year 2020. How do I calculate or estimate this probability?

I know that if I do a regression, I can find what the regression line predicts the temperature at 2020. But how can I find like a numerical probability? How would I go about using max likelihood?

Thanks!

Comment: Find the sample std deviation of the differences in temperature for each year from that predicted by the regression line. Assume a normal distribution with that std deviation for the temperature in 2020.

Comment: I thought of that at first, but then was unsure because my sample size was quite small. Is it still safe to assume a normal distribution?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the small sample size means that your std deviation value could be unreliable. But it is the quality of the std deviation that is affected by this, not the question of what distribution you should use. Normal distribution is used when it there is no evidence of bias. That is, there is reason to believe that the number of samples below average by some amount will be about the same as the number of samples above average by the same amount. Bias would be expected if we have a lot of years a little above average and a few years that were bitterly cold, or vice versa. But this is not observed.